# External Java script file is not working which contain Navbar Submenu code

Tags: javascript, html

I want to design a fixed height side nav bar , the issue i am facing is when i place the java script code inside html file its work fine but when i place the same code in external JS file it does not work
Here is my HTML File

```js
/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */

var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) 
{
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() 
  {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block")
    {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } 
    else 
    {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
/* Fixed sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
/* Some media queries for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Search</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu inside the side navigation.</p>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Some random text..</p>
</div>
</body>
<script src="abc.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: try putting script src="abc.js" before you call font-awesome , and see if it works. My guess is Net at your end is slow, hence it keeps on waiting to pull font-awesome and then load abc.js , thus obstructing the UI

Comment: are you sure the JS file is being loaded? where did you put(the folder structure) the abc.js file?

Comment: when you say the code doesn't work, what do you mean - is it not detecting your js file or it is but not doing what it's supposed to do. Try to add some 'console.log' into the js file to see.

Comment: Open your console and the network tab - you are probably pointing to wrong file. In your network tab, you should probably see 404 error on abc.js. I copied your HTML and created the abc.js like in your code and everything works fine

Comment: where i put my JS file it work for all other function i am using or calling but this specific peace of code(JS) is not working/loading which i mention above in the question...

Answer (score 1):

This line `<script src="abc.js"></script>` should be in **head** tag, i.e:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>...</style>
<script src="abc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
```

Or inside the body.

```
<body>
  ....
  <script src="abc.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: where he loads it doesn't make any difference if it is not working!

Comment: why downvote? it's actually a good catch that the original poster put his <script> outside of the body AND head tags.

Comment: Good catch with putting that inside the body tag. Although it should work the way it is already. At least it works in Chrome. I gave you upvote as downvote was unfair. One additional note - if you put your JS file in the HEAD then you should wait for "DOMContentLoaded" event before running code like document.getElemenById etc. because at the time you run your JS the DOM isn't fully loaded yet so you would get null on the query.

Comment: Putting it in the **head** will **break** things because the script tries to access the DOM and the elements won't exist at the time it runs if you put it in the **head**. While the script **should** be inside the **body**, browser error correction rules means this won't make any difference.

Comment: where i put my JS file it work for all other function i am using or calling but this specific peace of code(JS) is not working/loading which i mention above in the question...

Comment: Your JS code works fine, could you please specify you project structure or console log? It seems like JS is not loading because of the file name.

Comment: project structure , both html and js file are placed in same folder,

Comment: Are you using a framework or a specific environment? I think that could be the problem. If so please could you specify which framework?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script is missing the file.
It should be for example..

```html
<script src="scripts/abc.js"></script>
```